# Performance Impact on Service Broker WAITFOR RECEIVE with no TIMEOUT

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, service-broker

What is the performance impact of having a WAITFOR RECEIVE with no TIMEOUT?

We have build a .Net service that is to receive messages from our SQL Server Service Broker queue and then send the messages to an ActiveMQ.

Instead of having the service poll the SQL Server Service Broker queue every 5 seconds what is then the performance impact if we do a WAITFOR RECEIVE on the queue with no TIMEOUT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation on `RECEIVE`:

> The statement waits until at least one message becomes available then
>   returns a result set that contains all message columns.

What will happen is that the `WAITFOR RECEIVE` will suspend and wait for a message to come in and only return when a message does come in.  If it never does, it will sit there forever.

This does not consume server resources (except for tying up a listener), but it makes it difficult to terminate the program that made the call if messages are received infrequently.  The nice thing about the `TIMEOUT` clause is that it gives your application a way to periodically check whether someone, say, requested that the program terminate.  Without a timeout that returns control to the calling thread and lets it check for whether it should exit itself, your only option is to forcibly terminate the thread from the outside.

The difference in impact on the server by cycling the call every 5 seconds as opposed to holding on indefinitely is so small as to be unmeasurable.